# Incron to copy new files

Tags: incron

I have CentOS 7 with installed and running incrond.

As I understand incrond service can monitor /var/www/html/uploads/ and if a new file is uploaded - then using  IN_CREATE we can do something. In my case I'd like to copy this new file to directory /var/www/html/uploads/new/

But when I try to use an incron job

```
/var/www/html/uploads/ IN_CREATE cp /var/www/html/uploads/new/
```

I have no a result.

I guess my raw example is wrong but I can't catch how to use INCRON to copy new files from monitoring directory to another location.

Thanks for any hints and ideas to try.

Answer (score 4):

The syntax of an incron entry is:

```
<path> <mask> <command>
```

If you monitor directory, then $@ contains the directory path and $# the file that triggered the event but if you monitor a file, then you have to use $@$#  which contains the complete path.

In your case the entry should look like:

```
/var/www/html/uploads/ IN_CREATE cp $@$# /var/www/html/uploads/new/
```

Answer (score 1):

I found much better solution on
[Stackexchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/24952/script-to-monitor-folder-for-new-files) using INOTIFY.

First

```
yum install inotify-tools
```

Then create a bash script, let's say dirmonit.sh like

```
inotifywait -m /var/www/html/uploads/ -e create -e moved_to |
    while read path action file; do
        echo "The file '$file' appeared in directory '$path' via '$action'"
        # do something with the file
    cp /var/www/html/uploads/$file /var/www/html/uploads/new/$file
    done
```

and start on shell background

```
nohup sh /scripts/dirmonit.sh &
```

Comment: Why is it better than incron?

Comment: Beginning with 0.5.11 incrond uses system() to run your command with very incomplete metachar filtering.  Filenames can contain arbitrary shell metachars - you can figure it out from there.

https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1370316

Until incrond fixes this, you are better off rolling your own using inotify (be sure to quote everything thoroughly when using shell - I would recommend python or C instead).  Which is sad - incrond was a nice idea.  

Note: you're ok if you can guarantee there are no nasty chars in filenames - but I still wouldn't use a root incrond script.

Comment: For instance, the dirmonit.sh example above can do nasty things when shell metachars are in the filename - because the author forgot to quote $file . . .